# Is there a way to get 4K monitor support on my computer?

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi

I've recently bought a 4K monitor with 2 HDMI cables, and 2 DisplayPort connections.

However, my old computer (Intel i3-4130 CPU, 3.40GhZ with an integrated GPU) only has a Dual DVI and a VGA connector.

VGA worked fine for my 1920x1080 (60hz) monitor. I don't think it'll work for my 4K monitor, and I'd like to know a way to connect my PC to 4K (30hz), before I spend 10 dollars on a VGA to DisplayPort adapter.

Comment: Please edit your question… Well, it depends: What is the exact make and model your computer is and what the exact make and model the video card in that computer is.

Comment: i3-4130CPU, 3.40GhZ, integrated card

Comment: Exact make and model please?

Comment: I don't think you can do thus without a discrete graphics card (which probably costs more then the value of the system - one if my systems suffers from a similar issue). DVI is not capable of 4k and VGA is not practically capable of it.

Comment: I thought Dual-DVI was capable of 4k@30HZ?

Comment: The best connection you could have without upgrading your graphics adapter is connecting the DVI out from the pc to the HDMI in on the monitor through a passive DVI>HDMI adapter (or adapter cable), although I doubt your integrated graphics is capable of outputting 3840x2160p @ 30hz, considering its' age.

Comment: I tried that, it worked at QHD@60HZ.